# Foreign Table that references ALL columns of the origin table

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to create a foreign table that lists all columns of the original table, like this somehow?

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE localschema.localtable (/* list all columns of foreign_table here */)
SERVER foreignserver
OPTIONS (schema_name 'foreign_schema', table_name 'foreign_table');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`:

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA foreign_schema LIMIT TO (foreign_table)
   FROM SERVER foreignserver INTO localschema;
```

If you need the foreign table name to be different, rename it.